# Error in ROS Install on Pandaboard: 'E: Package 'mercurial' has no installation candidate'

Tags: ros, rosinstall, pandaboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I installed Ububtu 11.04 headless on a PandaBoard. I'm using minicom.

I'm trying install ROS on a Pandaboard through minicom. I follow the web:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/pandaros

and the guide indicate:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

I introduce the first comand by minicom:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial`

and I received the next text in the minicom:

```
make subversion wget python-setuptools mercurialll build-essential python-yaml c 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mercurial is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mercurial' has no installation candidate
```

Can you help me please?
how can I install ROS?

Thanks so much

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10756/error-in-ros-install-on-pandaboard:-%27e:-package-%27mercurial%27-has-no-installation-candidate%27/) by [Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/909/eduardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi!!

Yes, it's strange. I did copy-paste of the comand, then I think that no had error write.

I don't understand good the "ports.ubuntu.com and universe turned on", I'm new with ROS and I only know a bit Linux SO, but I think that one of the steps that I followed in the guide was apt-get update.

I eliminated the word mercurial of the comand and the instalation was successfull. I'm not sure that it are good or correct and the ROS will run correctly.... :S. I can create new packages, directories,... I will try to work...

Thanks so much.

---

Originally posted by [Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/909/eduardo/) with karma: 26 on 2011-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
Check the file: /etc/apt/sources.list. There will probably be some commented lines starting with deb and ending with univserse. If you uncomment those and rerun apt-get update you enabled the universe repositories. Additional packages as mercurial will be available.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try "sudo apt-get install mercurial" by itself. Your results look strange. It looks like you thought you typed mercurial but entered mercurialll instead. Did you correct it in some places when you posted your message?

---

Originally posted by [JamesRonald](https://answers.ros.org/users/594/jamesronald/) with karma: 81 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1